# Rounding a value using fixed decimal places

Tags: typescript, math

I have a numerical input, 'value' that is getting floored when I input a value with decimal places exceeding my parameter amount (5).

For example, if I enter 1.99999 it works when I exit the cell. If I enter 1.999999 (6 decimals), it floors down to 1.00000.

```
    let integralPart = Math.floor(value);
    let fractionalPart = (value - integralPart);
    let result: string[] = [];
    let s = String(integralPart);
```

I'm trying to include an if statement to correct this bug

```
    if (fractionalPart.length > decimalPlaces) {
        to.fix(decimalplaces)
    }
```

Currently I get the error that says 'property length does not exist on type number'. Anyone have any suggestions? Fairly new to TS.

Comment: Well, it's a number, not a string. Would not recommend converting it to a string for that, but it would be an option.

Comment: Why is there a `floor` in the first place and not round to the number of digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve there. If you just want to round a value with fixed digits there are various ways of doing it.

If you want a string output:

```js
const digits = 5;
const toFixed = x => x.toLocaleString(undefined, {
  minimumFractionDigits: digits,
  maximumFractionDigits: digits
});

console.log(toFixed(1.99999));
console.log(toFixed(1.999999));
```

If you just want the number to not exceed a given precision:

```js
const digits = 5;
const shift = Math.pow(10, digits);
const round = x => {
  return Math.round(x * shift) / shift;
};

console.log(round(1.99999));
console.log(round(1.999999));
```

Comment: using what you've posted second, the rounding method, even when i plug in 1.999999 as 'value' it still appears as 1.00000 when i exit my cell.

Comment: That must be some logic in your cell component then. My code does not floor anything like that. What exactly are these "cells" you are talking about?

Comment: Also, please do not edit the question in ways that make responses out of place/redundant. You might want to ask a new question about properly configuring whatever component you are using.

Comment: Sure, I re-edited. Sorry if that was bad practice. I just know it's easier to repost code in my original question than in the comment sections. The cells I speak of are in an application we're building that involves cell edits.

Comment: Well, then i am pretty sure you should did into the implementation of these cells if you are not invoking any flooring operations.